# In Rails, how do I validate a model for a specific controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, controller

if I have a model that looks like the following:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :content, presence: true, on: :post_create_action
end

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
   @post = Post.new(post_params)
   if @post.validate(:post_index_action) && @post.save
     redirect_to post_path(@post)
   end
  end
end
```

I know the @post.validate doesn't work as I've described in the code, but I'm wondering if this is possible in rails.

Comment: Well, it _should_ work as described. Only you need to pass `:post_create_action` there, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible, and it's called validation context:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this functionality using `lambda`

**models/post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :post_creation
  validate :content, presence: true, if: lambda { self.post_creation == true }
end
```

**controllers/posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
   @post = Post.new(post_params)
   if @post.save
     redirect_to post_path(@post)
   else
     # Handle the validation errors
   end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(....).merge(post_creation: true)
  end
end
```

Comment: Huh, the answer from 40 minutes ago shows that it _is_ possible to have contextual validations without any additional accessors.

Comment: I have updated the answer. But when using context validation one has to explicitly call the validate method in the controller right?

Comment: `.validate` or `.valid?`, yes. On the other hand, no accessors and no extra form field :)

Comment: Thinking more about it, it feels unsafe to choose validations based on value of a form field provided by user. You can't trust user input.